# Is there a way to set `//@dart=2.12` for an entire package/lib/folder?

Tags: flutter, dart

When migrating large code bases to nnbd, it would be helpful if we could opt entire local packages in/out of NNBD. For example, I may want to migrate some of my leaf nodes first, like `/lib/helper_widgets/*` before moving onto the higher-order views.

Currently dart supports this on a per file basis using `// @dart=2.12` which is fairly tedious if your package has many files.

I was hoping I could do this with `lib` and `part of`, but this just gives me a compile error, to add a header to each file.

[Edit] A pragmatic solution here is to run something like `find . -name "*.dart" | xargs sed -i "1s/^/\/\/ @dart=2.9\n/"` on your project. That will put the 2.9 import in every file. At that pt, you can use find/replace to just turn on entire sub-directories of your /lib code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's gonna be either per file, or with the `pubspec.yaml`.  The pubspec method will change the entire package.  If you use `dart migrate`, that's one of the steps it performs. Then be sure to `dart pub upgrade`, because a different set of dependencies will then be available.

Comment: It's too bad they don't support this, seems one approach is to somehow inject // @ dart=2.9 into the first line of each file, at that point we can do find/replace on entire folders to toggle them on/off. 

The reason is when we turn nnbd on for our very large project, it's 900 errors. We need to proceed from a leaf-node-first way, even for our internal app code.

Comment: just to be clear, this would involve changing the sdk constraints, say to something like sdk: ">=2.9.0 <3.0.0" or sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0" in the pubspec.yaml file. I really want to opt-out of NNBD for personal projects

Comment: If you opt out of NNBD for personal projects, you'll be stuck running older unsupported libraries from pub.  Why limit yourself to that?